# Configure Intellij to support another java extension file

Tags: intellij-idea, file-type

I have some app that runs bean shell scripts (`*bsh`) and I absolutely love Intellij IDEA. And my bsh scripts are has syntax looks similar to java syntax. How can I add support of bsh files to make it behave like it is java source files?

I tried to add association at `Settings -> Editor -> File types` and all I got is general syntax highlight but it still doesn't support formatting and autocomplete so the `Code -> Reformat code` breaks all my formatting to left aligned text.

**UPD** BeanShell Box doesn't work. Maybe because of its outdating

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [BeanShell Box plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=1022).

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work at all. Seems like it isn't supported by all last versions of IDEA